# Option Tree not passing WordPress Theme Check

Tags: php, themes, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am having a problem uploading my theme to wordpress.org. The initial theme check fails with the below error..

```
REQUIRED: ot-settings-api.php. Themes should use add_theme_page() for adding admin pages.
Line 99: $theme_check_bs   = 'add_menu_page';
REQUIRED: ot-settings-api.php. Themes should use add_theme_page() for adding admin pages.
Line 100: $theme_check_bs2  = 'add_submenu_page';
REQUIRED: ot-cleanup-api.php. Themes should use add_theme_page() for adding admin pages.
Line 82: $theme_check_bs = 'add_menu_page';
```

I have integrated Option Tree framework into my team. But WordPres.org doesn't accept until the issue is resolved.. The funny thing is i downloaded few other themes from WordPress directory which uses Option Tree, I tested with the Theme Check Plugin and they all didn't pass, so how did they manage to upload their themes to the wordpress.org theme directory? How do i resolve the REQUIRED issue and upload my theme successfully..

Comment: same problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: No huykon225, unfortunately it appears WordPress changed their rules so there's no way to get pass this issue.